# Print out XML object on HTML page

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

Im trying to print out the request when i get a tagname from an XML request, however when i do it with document.write it only shows up as

```
[object Element]
```

The thing i want it to do, is to get the text inside my the tagname query and print it out on the html page
Here's my code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        var y = xhr.responseXML;
        var getTagname = y.getElementsByTagName("query");
        for (var i = 0; i < getTagname.length; i++){
          document.write(getTagname[i]) //This writes out [object Element]
```

The code itself doesnt seem to be wrong, because when i try it with console.log and look at the response, i can see that the selected query is printed out in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
document.write(getTagname[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

instead of

```
document.write(getTagname[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks! That works, im going to look up what nodevalue is

Comment: it's the value of the node